# Error : No provider for service in ES5 Angular2

Tags: angular

I have started learning Angular2 from [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/displaying-data.html). i have taken an example from this tutorial.

[created plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/46Sz18EWQaoEI6aI5jW5?p=preview)

**Component :**

```
function FriendService (){
  this.friendList = ['Wam','Pam','Sam','Cam'];
}

function PersonalInfo (friends){
  this.myName="Jam";

}
PersonalInfo.annotations = [
  new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
    selector : 'app',
    injectables :[FriendService]
  }),
  new angular.ViewAnnotation({
    template:'<h3>{{myName}} Friend\'s</h3>'
  }) 
]; 
PersonalInfo.parameters =[[FriendService]];
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  angular.bootstrap(PersonalInfo);
})
```

**View :**

```
  <body>
    <app></app>
  </body>
```

here i have injected FriendService to the component and also passed parameter to to PersonalInfo component. but it is giving error :

*No provider for FriendService! (PersonalInfo -> FriendService)*

anyone have any idea about this error ?

Answer (score 1):

## Update January 14, 2016 - angular2@^2.0.0-beta.1

This is the new syntax.

```
function FriendService(){
  this.friendList = ['Wam','Pam','Sam','Cam'];
}

var PersonalInfo = ng.core
  .Component({
    selector: 'app',
    providers: [FriendService]
  })
  .View({
    template:'<h3>{{myName}} Friend\'s</h3>'
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: [FriendService, function(friends){
      this.myName="Jam";
    }]
  })

ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(PersonalInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

From Angular 2 alpha-25+, `Component.injectables` has become `Component.appInjector`.

Also, I'm not certain that parameters require double square brackets. Though I could be wrong. You might want to consider using the [A library](https://github.com/angular/a) for writing ES5 annotations in Angular.

Try these changes:

```
PersonalInfo.annotations = [
  new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
    selector : 'app',
    appInjector :[FriendService]    // injectables -> appInjector
  }),
  new angular.ViewAnnotation({
    template:'<h3>{{myName}} Friend\'s</h3>'
  }) 
]; 
PersonalInfo.parameters =[FriendService];  // [[]] -> []
```